# Qt cannot open included file on ui_mainwindow.h

Tags: qt, include, qwidget, mainwindow

I am making a project in QT Creator 2.6. I am promoting a QWidget subclass called cPlotter, but when I try to compile the project, it fails because it cannot find the file cplotter.h. I figured out that this is because the file “ui_mainwindow.h” updates automatically including the file cplotter.h within brackets instead of quotes.

So, ui_mainwindow.h updates like:

```
#include < cplotter.h >
```

but it should be:

```
 #include “cplotter.h”
```

So, it is very annoying to edit by hand every time I change something on the GUI.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: Are you modifying the ui_mainwindow.h file?

Comment: Hang on, aren't `<cplotter.h>` and `"cplotter.h"` equivalent?  I thought choosing which one was stylistic decision rather than a syntactical one.

Comment: Diffrence between `<cplotter.h>`  and `"cplotter.h"` is just order of searching directories.

Comment: I know that, but in this case it only works by using quotes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
(or where cplotter.h)

Comment: Could you add an explanation, please?